# CircuitLab touch capability?

Tags: feature-request, bug, circuitlab

Since I've only accessed SE from my mobile devices for the last month now, I've begun noticing some interesting erm "*characteristics*" of the CircuitLab links on this site.

1. If browsing with "Request Desktop Site" disabled, I always get a "CircuitLab doesn't work on touch devices" message (wording may not be accurate, but same intent).
2. If I try to open CircuitLab while writing an original post with "Request Desktop Site" (RDS) enabled, I *usually* get that message, but once i  a while it opens (sorry, haven't tried to verify functionality yet, but it opens).
3. If I try to open CircuitLab while editing a post, or by clicking the "modify schematic" link, it *usually* opens (still haven't tried actually doing anything).

So... My question(s):
Is CircuitLab *rwally* incapable of working on touch-based input devices?

- If yes, then why the "opening glitch" & can we get that fixed?

  - How can we override if using a USBotg device with an attached mouse?
  - Can we put some pressure on CircuitLab to "make it compatible"?
- If no, can we disable/workaround the code CircuitLab uses to identify "touch devices" to skip that message & "get some work done"?

Comment: Circuitlab is run in an iframe, so everything you see happen is from CircuitLab's servers, same as if you went directly to their site. So this is not a EE.SE question.